# How to get currently selected node in a treeview

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

How is it possible to get the selected (clicked on) node in a treeview and return it as a string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Do note that you can obtain the selected node at any time using the [`TreeView.SelectedNode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx). You don't have to do it from within an event handler method. Something like: `MessageBox.Show(myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text)`

Comment: You are right, I assumed the OP wanted to get the name from the 'selection changed' event (because of the first comment of the OP).

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx

Maybe:

```
 MessageBox.Show(((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode.Text)
```

Or

```
 MessageBox.Show(((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode.Name)
```